# Chart.js v2: stacked group bar chart toggled to remove stacking

Tags: javascript, chart.js, dom-events

I have a stacked group bar chart with can be toggled to remove stacking. But it seems that since I have specify the "stack" property in the datasets, the bars are overlapped after I toggle to remove the stacking. And I have tried to remove the "stack" property when the toggle is not checked. But unfortunately it doesn't help.

[Stacked groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTFKI.png)

[Current unstack result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1byv8.png)

And this is what I want to achieve after toggled:
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5xYe.png)

How should I remove the "stack" property and get the chart updated when I toggled?
Thank you!!!

```js
const data = {
  labels: [2015, 2020, 2025, 2030],
  datasets: [{
      label: "b1",
      stack: "stack_bedarf",
      borderColor: 'rgb(166,197,54)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(165,196,54)',
      data: [
        127412,
        107311,
        92356,
        75093
      ],
      order: 0
    },
    {
      label: "b2",
      stack: "stack_bedarf",
      borderColor: 'rgba(20, 157, 206, 1)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(20, 157, 206, 1)',
      data: [
        127412,
        107311,
        92356,
        75093
      ],
      order: 2,
    },
    {
      label: "b3",
      stack: "stack_bedarf",
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      data: [
        127412,
        107311,
        92356,
        75093
      ],
      order: 4,
    },

    {
      label: "1",
      stack: "stack_p",
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(167,198,54,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(167,198,54)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [
        212526,
        45464, -97986, -217696
      ],
      order: 1,
    },
    {
      label: "2",
      stack: "stack_p",
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(20, 157, 206, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(20, 157, 206, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [
        340041,
        72742, -156778, -348314
      ],
      order: 3,

    },
    {
      label: "3",
      stack: "stack_p",
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [
        170021,
        36371, -78389, -174157
      ],
      order: 5,

    }
  ]
};

let toggle_chart;
window.onload = () => {
  const ctx_toggle = document.getElementById("toggleChart").getContext("2d");
  toggle_chart = new Chart(ctx_toggle, {
    type: "bar",
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'stacked toggle chart'
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true,
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            stacked: true
          }

        ]
      },
      tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        // mode: "x-axis",
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
            const tooltipValue = tooltipItems.yLabel;
            return tooltipValue !== 0 ?
              data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label + ": " + parseInt(tooltipValue).toLocaleString() : "";
          }
        }
      },


    },

  })
  document.getElementById("togBtn").addEventListener("change", toggleStack);
}

function toggleStack() {
  let isStacked;
  // assign the opposite value to "isStacked"
  isStacked = !document.getElementById("togBtn").checked;
  toggle_chart.options.scales = {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: isStacked
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: isStacked
    }]
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (isStacked === true) {
      data.datasets[i].stack = "stack_bedarf"
    } else {
      delete data.datasets[i].stack
    }
  }
  for (let i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
    if (isStacked === true) {
      data.datasets[i].stack = "stack_p"
    } else {
      delete data.datasets[i].stack
    }
  }

  toggle_chart.update({
    duration: 800
  });
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #2ab934;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #5e5e5e;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
  transform: translateX(55px);
}

.on {
  display: none;
  left: 35%;
}

.off {
  left: 65%;
}

.on,
.off {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input:checked+.slider .on {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+.slider .off {
  display: none;
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="toggleChart"></canvas>
<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" name="tog">
    <div class="slider round">
        <span class="on">Unstacked</span><span class="off">Stacked</span>
    </div>
</label>
```